# express4 bodyparser post array item is udefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, body-parser

I have an express application that uses bodyParser to get json content from a post request. If I write out the content of the whole body it looks like this:

```
{
  'device[group]': 'TESTGROUP',
  'device[name]': 'TESTNAME',
  'events[http][address]': 'http://192.168.77.11/api'
}
```

Immediately after I write out the content of events which gives me undefined. What am I doing wrong?

My code is as follows:

```
app.post('/settings', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.events); // undefined
```

Client side code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: postURL,
            data: {
                    "device": {
                        "group": $('#devicegroup').val(),
                        "name": $('#devicename').val()
                    },
                    "events": {
                        "http": {
                            "address": $('#httpaddress').val()
                        }
                    }
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'
        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Comment: Try like this, as events is a 2d array console.log(req.body.events[http][address]);

Comment: is the `bodyparser` dependency installed? if not then run `$npm install bodyparser --save` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need send data as [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), not as [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject):

```
$.ajax({
            url: postURL,
            data: JSON.stringify( {
                    "device": {
                        "group": $('#devicegroup').val(),
                        "name": $('#devicename').val()
                    },
                    "events": {
                        "http": {
                            "address": $('#httpaddress').val()
                        }
                    }
            } ),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        }).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Comment: I suppose I have to use JSON.parse(req.body) at the server after this, right? Unfortunately I have misteryous exceptions from the json parser, like 'Unexpected token: u' It seems that the string doesn't contained a well formed json string.

Comment: @Perrier No, you need just set `contentType` to `application/json` (see update).